# Glassmapper 5 GetItem in language version

Tags: glass-mapper

I need to extract an item with **Glassmapper** in specific language. But in **Glassmapper 5** this method  is marked as *"Obsolete"*:

```
 _sitecoreService.GetItem<IAvailableCountries>
                (Models.Constants.Items.CountryTagFolder, LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en"));
```

[image]

But I don`t see any overloaded version of *GetItem* where I can pass language as parameter.

What is the best practice to do it with Glassmapper 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use now either `GetItemByIdOptions` or `GetItemByPathOptions` (or other options) and pass language there, e.g.:

```
var options = new GetItemByIdOptions(guid) { Language = language };
var item = sitecoreService.GetItem<IAvailableCountries>(options);
```

Read more here:

https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/10/29/glass-mapper-part-2-of-2-what-is-new-and-changed-in-version-5/

Comment: Thank you! Exactly that I found.